# How create bootable usb windows 10 on ubuntu 14.04-16.04 with 32 bits?

Tags: dual-boot, usb, 16.04, windows-10

How create usb bootable windows 10? I have 32 bits and created usb windows 10 and won t boot to usb and say is not supported to boot. Running ubuntu 16.04 on acer zg5 and like to install windows 10 . Can dual boot? Creaete usb win with 32 bits no 64 bits. thx

Comment: Did you md5sum hashcheck the downloaded ISO?  What did you use to create the CD?  Did you burn the CD as slowly as possible?  What exact error message did you get?

Comment: Not have HARD DISC.Also can install windows 10 with usb. My little laptop without hard disc is efficient,power procces,and... can t play games. I want to install windows 10 with usb. CAn dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu? Running 32 bits and try WinUsb and getting error is invalid program or not supported... HOW TO FIx

Comment: WinUSB for 16.04 has a 32-bit package available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to install Windows 10 to a USB device and boot/run Windows from that device.  This is not an Ubuntu question, but look at http://lifehacker.com/how-to-run-a-portable-version-of-windows-from-a-usb-dri-1565509124 for a method to allow this.  Normally Windows does not run from USB, so never tried it myself.